# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running a `Rails` application.

app/workers/sample/fetch_book_report_worker.rb

```
class Sample::FetchBookReportWorker
 // body
end
```

app/workers/sample/fetch_student_report_worker.rb

```
class Sample::FetchStudentReportWorker
 // body
end
```

app/workers/sample/fetch_teacher_report_worker.rb

```
class Sample::FetchTeacherReportWorker
 // body
end
```

app/workers/sample/fetch_college_report_worker.rb

```
class Sample::FetchCollegeReportWorker
 // body
end
```

When I ran the above worker individually, I didn't see an issue. But I ran all the workers at the same time. I got the below error.

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Sample::FetchStudentReportWorker, expected /home/ubuntu/my-app/app/workers/sample/fetch_student_report_worker.rb to define it
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Could you put code where you call these classes?

Comment: @barmic For now, I am calling workers from Rails console? Originally it will be scheduled using whenever gem

Comment: @Galet, can you post a command you use to run all workers from console?

Comment: I am calling the workers in rails console as below at the same time. Sample::FetchBookReportWorker.perform_async Sample::FetchStudentReportWorker.perform_async Sample::FetchTeacherReportWorker.perform_async Sample::FetchCollegeReportWorker.perform_async

Comment: Do you have `app/workers/sample.rb` that defines `Sample` module?

Comment: No. I don't Sample module.

Comment: So why do you need to run them at the same time? Isn't getting it to work programatically sufficient?

Comment: @dan-klasson I am going to permissions to run the report for limited number of users in UI. So many users will trigger the same jobs.

Answer (score 5):

You can see autoload_paths to type this command.

```
bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
```

If you can't see .../app/workers/sample, add the `autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("app/workers/sample")
```

If it could causes problem in production mode, use the 'eager_load_paths'

referece from https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: since the error says: "expected /home/ubuntu/my-app/app/workers/sample/fetch_student_report_worker.rb to define it" would that not imply it already is in the autoload path, but it can't find it there, hence my concern that the filename is incorrect.

Comment: @Galet can you show me a part of code when loads the constant Sample::FetchStudentReportWorker?

Comment: @Brad I am calling the workers in rails console as below at the same time. Sample::FetchBookReportWorker.perform_async
Sample::FetchStudentReportWorker.perform_async
Sample::FetchTeacherReportWorker.perform_async
Sample::FetchCollegeReportWorker.perform_async

Comment: maybe spring is problem. $ bin/spring stop and rails console then run again. In sidekiq wiki, "NOTE: If you are testing this out in Rails console and you use spring you may need to stop spring so that you can access the new worker."

Comment: @ogelacinyc I have checked. spring is not running.

Answer (score 1):

One likely root cause for the `LoadError error` is, that as of Rails 5.2.0, there are changes to autoload, that require submodules (namespaces) to (at the least) be defined (as a constant).

In the original post's example, the `module Sample` should be defined in the `app/workers/sample.rb` file (as commented by Vasfed above).

Refer to this [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601195/2769838) for more details.